# Can a ticket be moved through a JIRA workflow when creating a Crucible review?

Tags: jira, atlassian-crucible

We have a JIRA setup, integrated with Crucible/Fisheye, and with a workflow step called "Under Code Review".  Right now developers create a code review, and that's linked to the JIRA ticket appropriately, via the "Source" and "Reviews" tabs.  This is great.

Is there a way to configure JIRA so that it automatically puts the ticket into the "Under Code Review" step once a Crucible review is associated with the ticket?

Comment: +1 - I'd love to be able to do this.

Comment: A few things that I've learned: (1) Listeners don't work.  There is no callback.  (2) the JIRA Fisheye Plugin queries Fisheye/Crucible upon access to the ticket and Source/Review tab.  It appears that this isn't possible, but I'm leaving this open in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer on the Atlassian Answers site (https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/2991/can-a-ticket-be-moved-through-a-jira-workflow-when-creating-a-crucible-review).  A new plugin has been created for JIRA v4.3+.  See the [Crucible Review-Issue Transitions Plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/68723)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a [Listener](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Listeners) to "watch" for posted reviews and execute the workflow transition if one is found.

Comment: Is there something out of the box that does this?  For that matter, are you sure that an event is fired when a review is posted?

Comment: I've added the base DebugListener and I don't see any events fired to the Listener when I create or summarize a review.